# ¿Como enviar parametros por metodo post desde la clase videoview de android?

Tags: android, android-studio, video

Tengo un servicio web donde estan alojados archivos multimedia, pero para acceder a estos recursos debes de estar autenticado previamente.

Estoy realizando una app para android para que se pueda ver este contenido desde el celular.

Mi problema es el siguiente, al momento de establecer en el elemento videoview de android la url , hay alguna manera de enviar parámetros en la url mediante metodo POST?

mi codigo resumido a mi problema es algo asi:

```
VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

String vidAddress = "https://video.mp4";
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);

vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

vidView.start();
```

lo anterior funciona si en la url agrego las credenciales en la url , pero por motivos de seguridad esto no es una buena practica, existe alguna manera para que envíe las credenciales mediante el método post usando la clase vídeo view o alguna otra clase?

Comment: Ppodrias usar `Volley ` para hacer peticiones y tienes la opcion de eniar parametros POST

Comment: Por lo que entiendo volley es una libreria independiente para peticiones http y no es recomendada para la descagra de archivos de grandes tamaños, y como seria la integracion con videview?

Comment: Quieres descargar ese video por medio del WebView o solo quieres visualizarlo por medio del WebView?

Comment: Visualizarlo atravez de webvideo